# Append values to [String : AnyObject] or [String : String]

Tags: swift, dictionary, parameters, alamofire

I want to append values to a variable of type `[String : AnyObject]` how do I do that? cause I can't do the ff.

```
var someObject:[String : AnyObject] = ["name":"John Diggle", "location":"Star City Prison"]

someObject.append(["work":"soldier"])        // does not work  (by that I mean there is no .append function like that of other collection types such as NSMutableArray and NSMutableDictionary
someObject = someObject + ["work":"soldier"] // does not work
```

I'm finding a way to make easier parameters for Alamofire since Alamofire.request uses `[String : AnyObject]`

Comment: yeah I noticed it after I posted it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The data type you have mentioned is called `Dictionary`. And Swift dictionary does not provide API `append(_ newElement:)`. Dictionary is a type of hash table. Each entry in the table is identified using its key.

If you want to add new item (key,value), simply add new value under a new key like that:

```
object["Work"] = "Soldier"
```

For more information read this doc [Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary)

Comment: ohhh so I've been looking at this at the wrong angle from the very beginning

Comment: someObject["Work"] = "Soldier" . may can do best understand

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
someObject["work"] = "soldier" as NSString
```

The problem we're trying to solve is that we don't get automatic bridging from String to NSString (NSString *is* an AnyObject, but String is not), so we have to cross the bridge ourselves by casting.

Comment: On the other hand, it might be better to work with `[String:String]` and don't cast until the moment comes to talk to Alamofire when you hand it the whole dictionary.

Comment: ohhhh. so that's how I add values.

Comment: If it helps you then please click on the accept button. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

**Initialize dictionary**

```
var dic = [String: Any]()
```

**or**

```
var dic : [String: Any] = ["firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe"]
```

**Append value**

```
dic["age"] = 25
```

**Update Value**

```
dic.updateValue("Jan", forKey: "firstName")
```